# The meaning of [ $? == 1 ] && return 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, test, exit-status

I need to understand this command:

```
[ $? == 1 ] && return 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression `$?` evaluates to the exit code of the previous command.

`&&` is a command separator which will run the second command if and only if the first command returns an exit code of zero.

`[` or `test` is a shell tool to make various comparative tests.

I should point out that `==` is the wrong test to use here as that is for *string* comparison; `-eq` is the equality test for *numerical* comparison.

So:  `[ $? -eq 1 ] && return 0` will look at the exit code of the immediately previous command, and compare it to `1`.  If there is a match, the command `return 0` will be executed (thereby bypassing what I presume to be subsequent commands in the function wherein this test lies).

The distinction between the usage of `==` and `-eq` is that `[ 01 -eq 1 ]` is true whilst `[ 01 == 1 ]` is false.

Comment: Good answer, covers everything. May also wanna mention `return` is used in functions, so OP's command probably belongs in a function somewhere

Comment: One step ahead of you (:

Comment: The difference between `=` and `-eq` probably doesn't matter here, since `$?` wouldn't usually contain leading zeroes. However, `==` is nonstandard, the standard operator is `=`.

Comment: `test`'s manual page indicates that `==` is synonymous with `=` for compatibility with other implementations.  Either way, the point is that `-eq` is the right tool for this comparison.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Which `tests` manual you checked ? `bash` man page mentions it,  but GNU `test` man page doesn't mention `==` operator at all, despite supporting it apparently. As far as what ilkkachu said,  he's probably referring to POSIX `test`, which indeed doesn't support `==`.

Comment: A better test, assuming one wants to test of any error and not a specific error code, would have been `[ "$?" -ne 0 ]`. The `$?` should be quoted. Also, its usually better to just use `utility || exit` or `if ! utility; then exit; fi`.

Comment: While I understand the reflexive "quote your variables", I think it's fair to make an exception for `$?`.  I also deliberately didn't bring up `[ $? -ne 0 ]` because I wanted to address the specific question in the OP and not get too far from the actual test in question.  Though I'd generally do `if ! do_thing; then oops; fi` rather than `thing; if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then oops; fi`.  But that's an whole other digression.

Comment: An unquoted `$?` would possibly be affected by digits in `$IFS`. Not that it's common, but...